# My JavaScript image slider work for just one round?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I read the W3Schools JavaScript Chapter and am trying to make an image slide. I did everything first and it works properly for the first round. For example lets say I click the next button it will keep sliding the slides till the end of the slideshow and then if I click once more it will reset every thing but never works after that. Also when I include the DocType deceleration it won't even work from the beginning.

Here is the HTML with CSS and JavaScript Code:

```
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
        <title>
          Project Name
        </title>

       <style>
*
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body
{
margin: 25px;
}

#slideshow
{
width : 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #000;
margin: 0 auto;

}

#slides
{
position: relative;
width: 900px;
height: 300px;
transition: 1s;

}

.slide
{
 width : 300px;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
}
      </style>
      </head>

<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slides">
            <img class ="slide" src="images/slide1.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="images/slide2.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="images/slide3.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="prev()">prev</button>
    <button onclick="next()">next</button>





    <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = 300;
        function next()
        {
            var slider = document.getElementById("slides");

            if(value == 900)
            {
                 slider.style.left = "0";
                 value = 300;        
            }
            else
                {
                    slider.style.right = value;
                    value += 300;
                }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: CSS `left` and `right` need a unit. Add `"px"`.

Comment: Still working for one round

Comment: Please apply basic grammar to your question: A sentence begins with a capital and ends with a period (.). This hurts my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardcoding JS values is bad practice.
One day you'll change the slider width in CSS and wonder what's going on with the JS part...

1. make it **responsive**
2. **calculate dynamically the number of slides** with JS
3. create a **counter** variable `c=0`
4. prev/next **manipulate your counter** value (loop using `%`)
5. tranistion-animate to `-100*c` in percentage `%`

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slides"),
    slide  = slider.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    tot = slide.length, c = 0;

function anim() {
  c = c<0 ? tot-1 : c%tot;
  slider.style.left= -100*c +"%";
}anim();

function next() { ++c; anim(); }
function prev() { --c; anim(); }
```

```css
#slideshow {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0; /* removes 4px inline-block gap */
  transition: 1s; -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

.slide {
  font-size: 1rem; /* restore font size */
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="slides">
    <div class="slide"
         style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/0fb);"></div>
    <div class="slide"
         style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/bf0);"></div>
    <div class="slide"
         style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/f0b);"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="prev()">prev</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Now that your slider is responsive, put into any container and it's width will accommodate.

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You must set back the `right` property to 0 once you finish one round. In your code you are setting `left` as 0 but your right still remains `900` . This is the problem, So change your code to set `right` to 0

```
        if(value == 900)
        {
             slider.style.right = "0";
             value = 300;        
        }
```